# Existe diferença além da sintaxe entre Self-Invoking-Functions?

Tags: javascript, sintaxe

Aprendi três formas de escrever *Self Invoking Functions*, *Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)*, e fiquei com uma dúvida se além da sintaxe exite alguma diferença entre elas.

```
(function () {
    console.log("Olá");
})();

(function () {
    console.log("Olá");
}());

! function () {
    console.log("Olá");
}();

void function () {
    console.log("Olá");
}();
```

OBS. A pergunta é referente as próprias *Self Invoking Functions* e não a diferença para funções "normais".

Comment: Ver também: [Qual a utilidade do Ponto de Exclamação (!) antes de se declarar funções em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157145)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Todas as versões acabam fazendo a mesma coisa, que é chamar a função anônima, e é mais uma questão de gosto. Eu prefiro a versão 2 `(function(){ ... }())` porque acho que fica mais claro com os parênteses envolta de toda a parte "mágica". Eu também não recomendo a versão 3 porque ela é mais rara e pode confundir outras pessoas.

Uma sugestão é botar um ponto-e-vírgula extra no começo de tudo para se proteger contra o caso de alguém esquecer de botar o ponto-e-vírgula numa das linhas que vem antes.

```
var x = foo

(function(){ ... }());
```

Nesse caso o Javascript vai parsear o programa como se foo fosse uma função:

```
var x = foo(function(){... }());
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu também prefiro a segunda sintaxe, mas é mais porque ela é válida no **JSLint**. Essa dica do _ponto e vírgula_ antes eu desconhecia, é bastante útil e já tive problemas com a linha anterior sem eles.

Comment: falando em jslint, eu prefiro bastante o JSHint. É um fork do jslint com bem mais funcionalidades e bem mais customizável.

Comment: Eu uso o JSHint pra projetos meus, mas no trabalho o Lint acaba sendo mais obrigatório...

Comment: Aff, eita gente atrasada :/