# Qual a utilidade do Ponto de Exclamação (!) antes de se declarar funções em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estava lendo um manual, e foi me pedido para começar as funções assim:

```
!function (){

}();
```

Apareceu esse ponto de exclamação. Qual é a finalidade dele?

Comment: Por que deram negativo ?

Comment: Sobre o operador em si: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37971/operador-not

Comment: Editei o título para evidenciar o contexto já existente no corpo da questão. Sobre o operador de negação, já existe pergunta e resposta no site, seria uma duplicata. No caso não é, pois se trata de contexto específico (começo da linha, antes de function, objetivo diferente da negação)

Comment: Relacionado (embora o título não dê essa ideia): [Qual a diferença entre criar um módulo normalmente e criar um módulo dentro de uma função?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120727/18246)

Comment: @jbueno Nessa linha tem essa minha resposta também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17355

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Experimente retirar a exclamação para ver o que acontece. Abra o console. Vai dar um erro de sintaxe, e a função não será executada.

A sintaxe do JavaScript interpreta a função como declaração somente se a linha começa com `function` (ignorando espaços e tabs). Declarações de função não podem ser imediatamente executadas com `()` no final, somente expressões podem ([mais sobre a diferença entre declaração e expressão de funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/74)). Então, o operador NOT nesse caso é apenas um truque para forçar a interpretação da função como expressão e permitir que ela seja imediatamente executada. Existem outras maneiras de fazer isso, como usar o operador unário `+` ou parênteses, entre outras:

```
+function() {
   // ...
}();


(function() {
   // ...
}());
```

Comment: Eu sempre uso o segundo, parece ser mais fácil de entender, excelente resposta!

Comment: Qual você indicaria para usar, o `!` o `+` ou `()`?

Comment: Em concordo com o Guilherme, @VirgilioNovic. Custumo usar parênteses. Mas se quiser economizar bytes, precisa partir para `+`, `!`, etc.

Comment: Vlw, obrigado!.

Answer (score 10):

O `!` antes da função faz com que ele seja tratado como uma expressão, para que possamos chamá-lo:

```
!function () {}()
```

Isso também irá retornar o booleano oposto do valor de retorno da função, neste caso `true`, por que`!undefined` é `true`.

Answer (score 8):

Observe esse código:

```
!function (){
    return true;
}();
```

Eis o que ele produz:

```
false
```

Já esse outro código:

```
!function (){
    return false;
}();
```

Produz isso:

```
true
```

Ou seja, ele inverte o resultado da função.

Para entender como funciona, vamos dividir o programa em três partes:

- `!`
- `function() { ... }`
- `();`

E então, vamos começar com a segunda parte, `function (){ ... }`, que declara uma função anônima.

Ao juntar a segunda parte com a terceira, `();`, temos que a função anônima declarada na segunda parte será invocada imediatamente, produzindo como resultado o que for retornado por essa função.

Ao juntar a primeira parte, `!`, com a segunda e a terceira, temos que será invertido o valor dado como resultado da invocação da função anônima.

Answer (score 5):

O símbolo de ! em javascript serve pra inverter uma expressão booleana.

Neste caso, como ele precede uma função, se a função retornar true, o resultado será false e vice-versa.

Funciona como o operador NOT.